# replacing an active directory server

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2003

I'd like to replace an SBS 2003 active directory server on our small LAN.  It also has sage services running, so I'd rather leave it online, instead of trying to move the sage stuff onto the replacement machine.

So instead, I'd just like to turn off DHCP, DNS, exchange, and file server capability on the server.

Is this difficult to do?

I've found DNS and DHCP services in the services section.  How can I disable the "AD domain controller" and file server aspect of it though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not difficult to do, but it's not a good idea either.

You should always have at least two Domain Controllers, and it doesn't sound like you do.  So you'd probably be better off just standing up a new Domain Controller, and leaving the existing one alone.  [Here's a Technet guide on promoting a second Domain Controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526434.aspx).

Having said that, [this is the Technet guide for demoting a Domain Controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc740017%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  And you do need to demote it properly - you'll have have nothing but a world of pain by shutting it off or disabling the services.

Comment: I would like to do that.  However, like I said, the domain controller also runs sage services, so I can't just turn it off and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

To demote a Domain Controller, you need to run `dcpromo.exe` and follow the wizard. Make sure **not** to check the box that says "This is the last DC in the domain."

You should *not* just simple stop the services on a Domain Controller. Instead, follow the complete demotion process to completion after other DCs have been promoted.

Comment: I think you can't actually demote a SBS DC w/o destroying the domain.

Comment: I was just going to drop the existing domain.  There are only 6 client PCs and I was replacing the AD DC with a samba4 service.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that this is a SBS DC. Never worked with it, so I can't speak to that. @lapin please edit your question to explicitly state this and don't rely on tags to fill in the details for you.

Comment: Oh god, why are you replacing AD with Samba and how do you plan on running Exchange without a real Domain Controller? I think you have some more homework to do before you start this.

Comment: SBS2003 machine is ancient.  I think the hardware dates back to 2003!  They don't need exchange, they just need a simple file server.  And why bring in fictional deities into your question?

Comment: @Zypher  I'm pretty sure you can, as long as you stand up another Domain Controller.  SBS throws a hissy fit if it's not the Global Catalog and FSMO role holder, can't co-exist with other SBS versions and (IIRC) goes into a reboot cycle if it's not domain-joined, but I'm pretty sure you can demote it, if you click through the multitude of "are you sure" dialogues.

Comment: @MDMarra - like I said, they don't need exchange here.  I've already migrated them away from exchange and onto google mail service (with their own domain name and web presence).  And they love it.  Exchange was dog slow.